# wordpress : php error in log keeps repeating

Tags: php, wordpress

```
[Sun May 20 13:35:20.221828 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10537] [client 127.0.0.1:47010] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in /home/124496.cloudwaysapps…class-wp-locale.php:231   
Stack trace:
#0 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php(112): WP_Locale->init()
#1 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(927): WP_Locale->__construct()
#2 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php(1569): wp_load_translations_early()
#3 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_Wpdb.php(145): wpdb->db_connect(true)
#4 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php(592): W3TC\\DbCache_Wpdb->db_connect()
#5 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_Wpdb.php(252): wpdb->__construct('redacted', 'redacted', 'redacted', 'redacted')
#6 /home/124496.cloudwaysapps.com/pu...
```

Comment: From https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_bloginfo-error-2/ it sounds like that function was deprecated and has since been removed. Maybe you are using an out of date plugin?

Comment: all my plugins are updated

Comment: @HilalPcnador Perhaps the plugin itself is deprecated as well. You could recreate the function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/), or just create a placeholder so it skips the error. Not sure what the call to that function does though so it could cause errors later..

Comment: I would recommend you to contact the Cloudways support to tackle this issue, since it's managed hosting and error is being triggered from WP core files. So it's something to do with their managed WP installation.

Comment: I did contact the support and I'm still waiting for their reply

Comment: To me, it looks like WordPress Core may still be using a deprecated function. See line 224 [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php). It may be worth [reporting to WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/).

Comment: my support said their servers are clean and this error is related to my application.

Comment: Collin I've reported it to wordpress wait and see :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and the issue was solved by **enabling** the `nd_mysqli` extension and **disabling** the `mysqli` extension from the "Select PHP version" configuration page of the hosting provider, after selecting PHP 7.